# How to hide current div once you click a new div that shows a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to hide current div once you click a new div that shows a new one. 
the code below it will show and hide div, but what im trying to do once you click the first item and click another item both of them will show up how can i make it possible once you clock another item the first item that you click will hide

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display == "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function myDIVS() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIVS");
  if (x.style.display == "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="career-list">
  <li class="career-item"> <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"> Foreman </a> </li>
  <li class="career-item"> <a href="#" onclick="myDIVS()"> Foreman </a> </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIV">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME </h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIVS">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME TWO </h3>
</div>
```

**Second Code** *(But its not closing once you click the same item)*

HTML

```
<ul class="career-list">
  <li class="career-item"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIV"> Foreman </a> </li>
  <li class="career-item"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIVS"> Foreman </a> </li>
  <li class="career-item"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIVSS"> Foreman </a> </li>
  <li class="career-item"> Foreman </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li').click(function() {
    $('.Info-div').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).find('a').data('id')).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the another div in the `else` block:

```js
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("myDIVS").style.display = 'none';
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var y = document.getElementById("myDIVS");
    if (x.style.display == "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function myDIVS() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myDIVS");
     var y = document.getElementById("myDIV");
     if (x.style.display == "block") {
         x.style.display = "none";
     } else {
         x.style.display = "block";
         y.style.display = "none";
     }
 }
```

```html
<ul class="career-list">
  <li class="career-item"> <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"> Foreman </a> </li>
  <li class="career-item"> <a href="#" onclick="myDIVS()"> Foreman </a> </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIV">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME </h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIVS">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME TWO </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write functions for every `<a>` tag...

- First get all the `<a>` tag in an array using `querySelectorAll`
- Then use javascript `forEach` to add a click event on every `<a>`
- Use for loop to set `display:none` to all the divs
- Then set the `display:block` to that `div` which has same `id` value as of `data-id` on `<a>` click
- And to toggle the same div use a `if` condition and if that condition become true, exit the function using `return`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-id]");
var div = document.querySelectorAll(".Info-div");
anchor.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var dataID = elem.getAttribute('data-id');
    var divID = document.getElementById(dataID);
    //to toggle the div
    if (divID.style.display === "block") {
      divID.style.display = "none";
      return;
    }
    //for all divs
    for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
      div[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    //for currentDiv
    divID.style.display = "block";
  })
})
```

```css
.Info-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="career-list">
  <li class="career-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIV">Foreman</a>
  </li>
  <li class="career-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIVS"> Foreman </a>
  </li>
  <li class="career-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIVSS"> Foreman </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIV">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME ONE</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIVS">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME TWO </h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIVSS">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME THREE </h3>
</div>
```

And if you are looking for the **jQuery** solution, you have to use `toggle()` to show/hide the same div and `hide()` to hide other divs

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(".career-list li a").on("click", function() {
  var clickedItemId = "#" + $(this).data("id");
  if (!$(clickedItemId).is(":visible")) {
    $(".Info-div").hide();
  }
  $(clickedItemId).toggle();
})
```

```css
.Info-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="career-list">
  <li class="career-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIV">Foreman</a>
  </li>
  <li class="career-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIVS"> Foreman </a>
  </li>
  <li class="career-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="myDIVSS"> Foreman </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIV">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME ONE</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIVS">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME TWO </h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 Info-div" id="myDIVSS">
  <h3> SEND US YOUR RESUME THREE </h3>
</div>
```